# How to use DynamicRouteValueTransformer to switch between 2 controllers and actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-routing

I have 2 similar controllers in different areas that I am trying to route depending on the user type. For example the two controllers have the index action that is supposed to show the home page;

```
WebApp.Areas.Candidate.Controllers.SocialController.Index
WebApp.Areas.Agent.Controllers.SocialController.Index
```

Currently when I add the `HttpGet("")` attribute to both actions I get the exception; `AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:`

So I have removed the attribute and created a `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` to try and dynamically change which controller and action the "/" endpoint should use but the transformer is not using my changes. The transformer looks like this;

```
public class UserModeTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
{
    public readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public UserModeTransformer(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        values = new RouteValueDictionary();
        values["controller"] = "SocialController";
        values["action"] = "Index";
        return values;
    }
    public override async ValueTask<IReadOnlyList<Endpoint>> FilterAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values, IReadOnlyList<Endpoint> endpoints)
    {
        return endpoints;
    }
}
```

For now I just set the `RouteValueDictionary values` to see whether it works but no matter which controller I change it to the `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` does not work.

I have tried to look for documentations about DynamicRouteValueTransformer  but I can't find any. I am using ASP.NET Core 7.

**Update**
Even having just this transform on the route without any user check returns 404;

```
public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            values = new RouteValueDictionary();
            values["area"] = "Candidate";
            values["controller"] = "SocialController";
            values["action"] = "Index"; 
            return values;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this before, But after searching some related information, I create a working demo. I am not sure if it is what you want, Hope it can give you some help.

There are two areas in my project:

```
IdentityTest\Areas\Authenticate\Views\Social\Index.cshtml
```

and

```
IdentityTest\Areas\Candidate\Views\Social\Index.cshtml
```

Because I don't know what's the user type in your application, So here is my logic: When user don't login ,when he type '/' in url, it will route to 'Home/Index' normally. After user log in, when he type '/' in url, project will route to area depend on user's name, If username is `123456@gmail.com` it will route to `Authenticate\Social\Index`, the other will route to `Candidate\Social\Index`

```
public class UserModeTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
    {
        public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            values = new RouteValueDictionary();
            if (username != null)
            {
                values["area"] = username == "123456@gmail.com" ? "Authenticate" : "Candidate";
                values["controller"] = "Social";
                values["action"] = "Index";

                return values;
            }
            else
            {
                values["controller"] = "Home";
                values["action"] = "Index";
                return values;
            }
        }
    }
```

register and use it in program.cs

```
            builder.Services.AddScoped<UserModeTransformer>();
            //............

            app.MapDynamicControllerRoute<UserModeTransformer>("");

            app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "MyArea",
            pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            

            app.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "default",
               pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            app.MapRazorPages();

            app.Run();
```

[image]

Comment: My problem is it always returns 404. Let's ignore the user condition check; Even a simple transform is not seen although it gets executed like the one I have added above

Comment: which step will return 404, I don't get this error in  my demo, I think it works as you expect

Comment: Have you configured `MapControllerRoute` like what i updated in my answer?

Comment: Do I have to add the ``[HttpGet("/")]`` to any of the controller actions?

Comment: no, don't add any route attribute

Comment: @Never_se Have you solved this issue now

Comment: No, I am still trying. I created a new project and tried your solution but it does not seem to work. I will try again.

Comment: But from the gif i provided, It seems what you want.

Comment: So basically you don't have to worry about the authentication part. Just being able to call either one of 2 controller actions using just 1 URL depending on particular condition. Even just going into the transformer and changing the values[] to any of the controller actions does not work. I think I just get a 404 error until I add the HttpGet attribute. I once managed to get it to work by just setting the HttpGet attribute on one of the controller actions and somehow changing it in middlewhere but that stopped working all of a sudden. I will try again properly I see what you're trying to do...

Comment: So basically going into this transformer method ``public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)`` and just setting the values to the area, contoller, action, ASP.NET does not apply the change just bypasses it and returns 404.

Comment: My problem was I was setting SocialController instead of Social. But it looks like I can't access the session in ``DynamicRouteValueTransformer``

Comment: After request enter `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` , will it generate correct Url?

Comment: It does not generate a url. It just passes it on to the right action.  I ended up using ``IdentityDbContext`` instead to check the user type in the database because I have access to that in ``DynamicRouteValueTransformer``

Comment: Basically ``DynamicRouteValueTransformer`` does not provide access to the session. It has not been created yet probably.